# After migrating my wordpress, the template sends Fatal Errors calling to functions

Tags: wordpress, migration

I just migrated my website from Hostinger (where I was trying my wordpress) to a new server and I keep receiving the following errror:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function consulting_get_header() in /home/rysx10ho/public_html/wp-content/themes/consulting/page.php on line 1

I don't know why this happens because in the other server it works fine but in this one it doesn't and I copied the exact same files and the database just changing the wp-config.

Comment: What about the phpversion?

Comment: is there any plugins required by your theme?

the function is your themes default.

Comment: Share the complete code file of page.php here